# Why does this static import not compile

Tags: java, static-import

Below class causes a compile error at line  `println("Hello World!");` : `The method println(String) is undefined for the type StaticImport` :

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class StaticImport {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        println("Hello World!");
        out.println("Considering a circle with a diameter of 5 cm, it has:");
        out.println("A circumference of " + (PI * 5) + " cm");
        out.println("And an area of " + (PI * pow(2.5,2)) + " sq. cm");
    }
}
```

Why can the pow method be accessed in java.lang.Math without explicitly importing pow , unlike the println method where the method name 'out' needs to be used ?

Comment: `out` is a static member of `System`, containing a PrintWriter reference.  `println` is not a static method, but rather an instance method of the PrintWriter instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With static import, you can access the direct members of a class without fully qualifying it.  Your static import allows you to access `out` directly, because it's a member of `System`, and `pow` directly, because it's a member of `Math`.  But neither `Math` nor `System` has the method `println`; `PrintWriter` does (the type of `out`).

Your static import...

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
//...
println("Hello World!");
```

... is equivalent to the following code, which we can see wouldn't compile:

```
System.println("Hello World!");
```

Answer (score 5):

`println` is a method belonging to the `out` member of the `System` class. Without that qualifier, Java has no idea what `println` is.

When you do a static import, you can access the members of a class without having to provide the fully-qualified name. So your static import of `java.lang.System` lets you access everything that `System` has. This means that you can access `out` (a `PrintWriter` instance) which belongs to `System`. But it does *not* mean that you can access `println` directly because that belongs to `out`. So you have to tell Java how to get to `println` by going through `out` first.

Look at it this way. Assume you have the following structure:

```
MyClass
   |
   +---Something
   |      |
   |      +---- methodOne
   |      |
   |      +---- methodTwo
   |      |
   |      +---- OtherThing
   |                |
   |                +---- otherMethodOne
   |                |
   |                +---- otherMethodTwo
   +---method
```

If you did a static import with `MyClass.*`:

- You have access to `method()` (Java translates this to `MyClass.method()`)
- You have access to`Something`. (Java translates this to `MyClass.Something`)
- You *do not* have raw access to other stuff under `Something`. For example, you cannot simply call `methodOne()` because Java will translate that to `MyClass.methodOne()`, and there is no method called `methodOne()` under `MyClass`. That method belongs to `Something`, so you *can* do `Something.methodOne()`, or `Something.OtherThing.otherMethodOne()`.

If you did a static import with `MyClass.Something.*`:

- You have access to `methodOne`. (Java translates this to `MyClass.Something.methodOne`)
- You have access to `methodTwo`. (Java translates this to `MyClass.Something.methodTwo`)
- You have access to `OtherThing`. (Java translates this to `MyClass.Something.OtherThing`)
- You *do not* have raw access to `otherMethodOne` or `otherMethodTwo`; you will need to do `OtherThing.otherMethodOne()` or `OtherThing.otherMethodTwo()`.
- You *do not* have access to `method`, because Java translates that to `MyClass.Something.method`, and there is no such method in the `Something` class.

Answer (score 0):

pow is a static method of Math class so you can access it without creating object of Math class if you have written import java.lang.Math statement at top, on the other hand out is an member of System class of type PrintStream and println() is a method of PrintStream class and it is not static, so you can't access it in a static way as non-static functions can't be called without creating objects. You can also refer to this link for more about PrintStream
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html